# stellarium ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, official-repositories

When upgrading to ubuntu 16.04, my stellarium 0.10 was automatically upgraded to 0.14.3. I do not want any of this 3D features (only 1 eye left). Tried to downgrade to 0.10. and 0.12 which apt-get could not find. ?which repository to include in /etc/apt/sources.list, to get the latest version without 3D?      Or what else?

Comment: It looks like it should be possible to prevent the 3D landscapes plugin from loading by setting `Scenery3dMgr` to `false` in the `[plugins_load_at_startup]` of the [Stellarium configuration file](http://www.stellarium.org/wiki/index.php/Configuration_file#Section_.5Bplugins_load_at_startup.5D)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the trouble, have to postpone working on the problem.